# google.ads.AdView not take the full width of screen in samsung galaxy notes

Tags: android, admob, adview

I am displaying a `google.ads.AdView` in my app at the bottom of the screen. All works fine. But the only problem is that it doesn't take the full width of the screen while showing in `Samsung galaxy note`, however while displaying in `Nexus s` it takes the full width of the screen.

Why this happens, is there is a way to solve this issue?

**My XML Layout where I put my `google.ads.AdView` is:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a14e5222d46c63d"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is your admob sdk version ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The width of the AdView varies depending on the attribute adSize. You can check the various values for this attribute in https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner#banner_size.  You can use the `SMART_BANNER` constant in case you are using v6.0.0 or later of AbMob.

```
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="yourAdUnitId"                         
                     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Comment: I used it as u said but it doesn't show add instead it shows the  following message in the add view..which i updated in my screen shot..

Comment: What is your AdMob SDK version? Have you tried the other adSizes - IAB_BANNER for example? And have you specified the right adUnitId?

Comment: its 6.0.0...No i haven't and in the manifest i already write this <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity

Comment: Admob needs `<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`. Follow their guide at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals

Comment: Moreever when i use the whole thing it shows error in manifest file as string type not allowded in config changes

Comment: You seem to have a problem with the Android SDK that you are using. Make sure you are using 3.2 (API level 13) for building. Search for other posts on SO about similar errors.

Comment: The `SMART_BANNER` is hidden in landscape

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions. First try setting the width to match_parent. If this isn't possible with addmob then I'd suggest that you center it with layout_gravity="center" so it looks less silly :)